# Python if and else

Tags: python

my code always gives the "Have a nice day", where have i gone wrong

```
import random
random_choice = ['Noob', 'Average', 'Pro', 'Expert']

name = input('What is your gamername? ')

print(name, 'is a', random.choice(random_choice), 'Gamer')

if random.choice == 'Noob':
    print('Im afraid there is nothing to be done')
else:
    print('Have a Nice Day', name)
```

Output is always

```
What is your gamername? (name=
Gamerman is a (Random) Gamer
Have a Nice Day (name)
```

Comment: `random.choice` is a function. It does not equal "Noob".

Comment: How do i make it check what the random function equals?

Comment: Store the result of your `random.choice(...)` call in a variable.

Comment: 'if random.choice(random_choice) == "Noob" ' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the function random.choice in your if statement.

Save the random name as a variable and check it.

```
import random

random_choice = ['Noob', 'Average', 'Pro', 'Expert']

name = input('What is your gamername? ')

random_name = random.choice(random_choice)

print(name, 'is a', random_name, 'Gamer')

if random_name == 'Noob':
    print('Im afraid there is nothing to be done')
else:
    print('Have a Nice Day', name)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked the way it should, so by creating a variable for the randomly generated answer its a lot less messy?

Comment: It means that it will stay constant. You only want to pick a random name once

Answer (score 3):

`if random.choice == 'Noob':` will never evaluate to True because `random.choice` is a function, and a function is never equal to a string.

When you call `random.choice` the first time, assign it to a variable. Then you can compare against that variable in your conditional.

```
import random
random_choice = ['Noob', 'Average', 'Pro', 'Expert']

name = input('What is your gamername? ')

gamer_kind = random.choice(random_choice)
print(name, 'is a', gamer_kind, 'Gamer')

if gamer_kind == 'Noob':
    print('Im afraid there is nothing to be done')
else:
    print('Have a Nice Day', name)
```